# Best way to manage Data with Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am creating a social app and will be handling large amounts of data. I have a certain part of my app where you can create four different types of events. My question is, would it be better to separate these four types into different classes: `eventType_One`, `eventType_Two`, `eventType_Three`, and `eventType_Four` to create smaller queries?

Or should I put all the events into one class `events`, therefore only creating one API request instead of four. On several pages I need to query through each class. I also will only have the basic plan: 30 requests

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a class `EventType` and an `Event` having the `EventType` as a relation. So you fetch the available types once and then your desired events. You want to limit the number of API calls as much as possible to a) not exceed your free plan and b) have fewer requests on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar social app and I modeled it after parses AnyPic. Parse uses 1 Class `Activity` which handles activities like: likes, comments, and follows. You can add your own events/activities to it if needed. Checkout [AnyPic](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic)

If you need to do something like photo, video, or galleries, I would recommend turning the photo class into a post class and adding a type field. Either way using the AnyPic model you should be able to add activities/events as needed.